# Can I use the same USB C to power and program a Raspberry Pi CM4?

Tags: power

I'm currently making a RP CM4 breakout board and I want to use a single USB-C to upload the OS and power it. To achieve this I made the following PCB:
[image]

With this setup I could also plug in a USB drive to upload files and stuff. There is one data+power out USB-C that plugs into to the breakout board one power in and two data ins just in case the USB-C somehow doesn't work. The sstxp pin can be grounded with the jumper and on the side of the carrier board it detects if the sstxp is grounded and if yes then it grounds nrpiboot and pulls USB_OTG_ID high so that it becomes a device. This is needed so that the carrier board knows if the programmer board is present. I only want to have one ISB-C because this will go into a case where it will control a display and I don't want to have an extra port unnecessarily.
So my question is are there any potential problems with this design?
I know this would be a question to ask on the Raspberry Pi forum but I already did and got no answer. I appreciate any help.

Comment: No reason why you couldn't use the same.  Pi as a usb slave offering a tty line has been around for ages... You may have to figure out just how to structure the network so that Pi gets all the rights you need (sounds like you want it to be the master of some drives so using it as just a slave may not be what you want)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just wanted to check if there's any major flaw in the design.